# Passing an Object via Servlet and reading it in YUI

Tags: javascript, servlets, yui

Hi I am trying to pass an object from a servlet to the YUI javascript code. Here is the class declaration of the object I am willing to pass:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Favourite implements Serializable {
List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> host = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> port = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

And this is how I am trying to send it through the servlet.

```
response.setContentType("application/x-java-serialized-object");
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream(); 
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
Favourite data = new Favourite();
// some code to manipulate the "data" instance
out.writeObject(data);
```

I am confused about how would I read this object in YUI. Please suggest a way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much doubt you can get YUI to deserialize the Java serialization bytestream.

Instead, I'd use [JSON](http://json.org). Provide a means of serializing your `Favorite` instances to JSON strings, and send that as the response (using the content type "application/json"). You can find multiple JSON encoders (serializers/stringifiers) for Java (including from the link above). YUI provides [JSON deserialization](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/).

Using JSON or XML as your on-the-wire format is by far the most current and popular means of sending data (as opposed to markup) between the client and the server in web apps. In my experience, JSON is overtaking XML a bit, partially because it's just so easy to use, but XML was there first (in fact, XML is the X in "ajax" — **A**synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **X**ML).

Comment: If I am not wrong, I think it possible to pass a Java serialized object to Jquery and deserialize it, also suggest me weather to use JQuery or YUI.

Comment: @aditya: No offense, but I'm pretty sure you're wrong. There's certainly no Java deserialization support built into jQuery, and I've never heard of a plug-in for it. The (default) Java serialization process produces binary data that isn't well-suited to being transmitted to, and then deserialized by, client-side JavaScript. It may be *possible*, but it's not remotely standard practice. Re YUI vs. jQuery: It's totally up to you (and you have about a dozen other choices). jQuery probably has an edge in terms of adoption, and is independent of any single large company (despite ties to Microsoft).

Comment: Thanks for the help I was able to make up a JSON object and parse it in YUI.

Comment: @aditya: Excellent, that's probably the best way to go right now.

Answer (score 0):

YUI won't be able to read a Java serialized object (binary data, with a Java specific format). You should use an open format, readable from JavaSCript, like XML or JSON, to transfer your object.

Comment: Please help me out, I am new to YUI and have little knowledge about it. If I transfer an object in XML or JSON format how would I read it.

Comment: Read http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/json/ for JSON and YUI. If you're doing AJAX and return XML, the the XML DOM tree will be available in the responseXML property of the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: assuming you are doing a AJAX call and return a JSON array, you would do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/rbYKj/ (using yui3)

Comment: Thank you for the help I was able to do so.